# Photo/Image distribution system

Tags: file-management, photography

I work for a fashion company. We deal with many, many photos in various stages of release.

Are there any commercial systems which handle the distribution of photos to various endpoints? These endpoints include customer and company websites, 3rd party software which makes use of the images and also internal archive locations.

1. As these endpoints are varied and all come with their own specific
   requirements, the system will need to allow for custom endpoints.
2. It would be nice if the photos could also be archived, or at least,
   managed by this system.

I can only find programs which manage photos for individual users.

If there is nothing specific, are there any systems which can be modified or built into a custom toolchain (if this makes sense at all)?

Free or commercial systems are both OK.